# display-posts shortcode attributes have no effect

Tags: posts, shortcode

I need to list some specific posts on a `page`.

I discovered the `[display-posts]` shortcode feature but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
[display-posts posts_per_page="2"]
```

Also trying a more specific query (all values copied from IDE):

```
[display-posts post_type="products" taxonomy="products_category" tax_term="products-books" include_excerpt="true"]
```

All I get is a generic list of 5 uncategorized posts no matter what attributes I enter.

It feels the filters are not being applied at all, because if they were, and e.g. the values had some typo, I believe it'd show 0 posts instead of 5 random ones.

Tried disabling all plugins. Wordpress version is 3.9.3.

I'm using this as a reference: [support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode](http://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/).

Please help

Comment: [That shortcode is not included in WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode), it is a feature of WordPress.com, which is [off-topic here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @cybmeta thank you for pointing that out. But why does it work then? It showed me 5 posts even after I've disabled all plugins (by renaming the `plugins` folder to something different)?

Comment: I can not know. It is not in WordPress for sure. Try to [download WordPress](https://wordpress.org/download/) and make a clean install to check it by yourself.

Comment: @TheSexiestManinJamaica: Maybe you have any plugin installed for that shortcode like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/installation/ ?

Comment: *I discovered the [display-posts] shortcode feature* - can you please show us from where did you *discover* the shortcode?